# Report not searching full description/text box

Tags: reporting

Short background:
Before we moved to salesforce we had a lot of data in a description box (tags related to that contact). We used these tags to pull out lists and run reports. This data, when moving to Salesforce, now exists in a custom text box.

Current problem:
When I now run a report in Salesforce and search for the tags in the text box, only a selection of all contacts with those tags started showing up. I did multiple reports and set-ups trying to figure out the problem and I believe it might be caused due to the following: a word count limit, for the report to search through the text box.

I've done a few tests and all contacts with the relevant tags listed within a 235 character count show up. All contacts with the relevant tags listed after 235 character count disappears/wont show on my reports.

Questions 1:
Can we remove or change the character count limit for the report search?

Question 2:
Does reporting have any other such limits?

edit; referring to character count with  spaces, instead of word count.

Comment: The "solution" here is to convert those tags to tags; Salesforce does have a tagging system you can use built-in. It's fairly trivial, but will require a bit of work to massage the data.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I'll do some research on the tagging system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your post, but it sounds like you are using a custom field of the Long Textarea data type.  You can verify this in Setup.

You can only search the beginning portion of a Long Textarea field with report filters:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212391&type=1

> Filters applied to custom Text Area (Long) fields only permit the
>   first 255 characters to be searched.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the quick reply. The text is in a custom field with the data type "Long Text Area(3000)". Unfortunately it doesn't seem we can change this based on your link. Interestingly enough, the quick search does search through the full Text Area. Is there a way to export a list directly from the quick search area?

Comment: No you can't export global search results in the UI.